# Writing to Excel worksheet but I keep receiving this error "The RPC server is unavailable"

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to write to an Excel worksheet but I keep receiving this error, "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)'"

```
ExcelIO excel = new ExcelIO(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\OneDrive\Desktop\CountiesWindSpeeds.xlsx", 1);

    public void WriteData(int i, int k, string value)
    {
        excel.WritetoCell(i, k, value);
        excel.Save();
    }
```

===========Above============ Form1.cs =====================

```
public class ExcelIO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Getting Excel path to open it
    /// </summary>
    private string path = "";

    private _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
    private Workbook wb;
    private Worksheet ws;

    public ExcelIO(string path, int sheet)
    {
        this.path = path;

        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];

    public void WritetoCell(int i, int j, string s)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 = s;
    }
```

===========Above============ ExcelIO.cs =====================

Comment: Seems you are missing Excel? Using the COM Interop ist pretty bug heavy in .Net days anyways. Maybe take a look at [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

Comment: I see OneDrive is in your path, try saving a local version to C:/Temp and try from there.

Comment: You're welcome @Araasai